# My walking speed is $1/4$ my running speed. I run for $3$ minutes and walk for $5$ minutes, going a total of $1700$m. What is my walking speed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Textbook problem:**

> My walking speed is $1/4$ of my running speed.  I run for $3$ minutes and then walk for $5$ minutes and have gone a total of $1700$ m.  What is my walking speed?

**My answer:** $100$ m/min.  If $x$ is the running speed, then the walking speed is $x/4$ so that the total distance 1700 equals $3x + \frac{5}{4}x$ using ''distance = (rate) x (time)". This yields $x = 400$ and so the walking speed is $100$ m/min.

**Textbook answer:** $80$ m/min.

**Question:** What am I missing?

Comment: You aren’t missing anything. The book might be wrong.

Comment: What book, and what edition?

Comment: "Calculus: The Analysis of Functions" by Peter D. Taylor, 1992. @DJohnM

Comment: It's in the "Diagnostics" section of the text, so before any calculus is introduced. 
 @DJohnM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct.  Sometimes there are errors in the answer key.

You can simplify the algebra by letting $x$ be your walking speed.  Then $4x$ is your running speed.  Since you travel a total of $1700~\text{m}$ when you run for three minutes and walk for five minutes, we obtain
\begin{align*}
(5~\text{min})x + 3[(4~\text{min}) & = 1700~\text{m}\\
5x~\text{min} + 12x~\text{min} & = 1700~\text{m}\\
17x~\text{min} & = 1700~\text{m}\\
x & = 100~\frac{\text{m}}{\text{min}}
\end{align*}